# By default does RDesktop use any encryption?

Tags: security, encryption, remote-desktop

When you use RDesktop to remote into another computer, is it traveling over the internet unencrypted? How secure is RDesktop, or should another application be used?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default all the **rdesktop** connections are encrypted.

You can use -e, -E option to disable encryption based on your need.

Alternatively you can use `ssh` to connect to a remote desktop with [x11 forwarding](http://support.suso.com/supki/SSH_Tutorial_for_Linux#X11_Session_Forwarding)

Syntax: `ssh -X user_name@the_server_IP_or_hostname.domainame`

Answer (score 1):

The RDP protocol does encrypt its messages by default as mention in previous answer however latest rdesktop sources does also have support for the RDPv5.2 feature SSL/TLS encryption  of the communication which is more commonly used approach of secure transmission.

Comment: improve your answer please